# Build Long-term Service android

Tags: android, background, intentservice

am trying to build android long-term service/intentService application.
after user open the application it has only one activity with single EditText to allow user input Authentication login code
after user input that the application should running subclass of WakefulBroadcastReceiver, and this subclass having alarm manager to running an intentService every 10mins

i am implemented [this example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/developers/samples/android/+/afac979/background/alarms/repeatingAlarm/Scheduler/src/com/example/android/scheduler?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F) 
but after one day 
the application doesn't back to send or receive message from the server

is there any practice can help to make application running the whole time

Answer (score 0):

Android stops normal service after some time(due to memory request)
You can Override this method in your service class to start the service again after it is stopped.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return START_STICKY;

}
```

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194519/android-service-stops-running-after-awhile-please-help) question.